# How can I order records by the numbers in a column of string versions of numbers with trailing letters?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of records. It has a column named `payment_number`, with type `nvarchar(255)`.
Its values are

- either string version of numbers, e.g. "1", "10"
- or string version of numbers appended with "S" or "F" (or maybe other one or more letters), e.g. "11S", "15F".

How can I order the records in the table by the numbers represented by "payment_number", ignoring the trailing letters? For example, "1", "2", "3", ..., "9", "10", "11S", ...,"15F".

Comment: Remove the letter from the string, and then `CAST`/`CONVERT` to an `int`. The former is not particularly easy in T-SQL in your have lots of different characters (a bunch of nested `REPLACE`s is one way, though `LEFT` and `PATINDEX` may also work hereif it's always a suffix). Seems like, ideally, the data should be 2 columns; one with your numeric data and then another (`NULL`able) column for your suffix.

Comment: `LEFT(payment_number, ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', payment_number), 0) - 1, 255))`. Deciphering this is left as an exercise.

Comment: Storing numerical data as a string is a well-documented anti pattern, any operations that require actual numerical operations like sorting will require string parsing and manipulation. If you know in advance the range of allowable values you could use `translate` (SQL2019) and `try_convert`, but it will never perform as well as just sorting by an integer column.

Answer (score 2):

This code will check the last letter or number of the string.
If it is a letter, then it will use everything to the left of that letter.
If there is no letter at the end, it will display the entire value.

I've included a temporary testing table in this example:

```
Declare @TestData TABLE
(
  payment_number      varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO @TestData (payment_number) select '1'
INSERT INTO @TestData (payment_number) select '2'
INSERT INTO @TestData (payment_number) select '3'
INSERT INTO @TestData (payment_number) select '9'
INSERT INTO @TestData (payment_number) select '10'
INSERT INTO @TestData (payment_number) select '11S'
INSERT INTO @TestData (payment_number) select '15F'

select ( case when right(t1.payment_number, 1) between 'A' and 'Z' 
              then left(t1.payment_number, len(t1.payment_number) -1 ) 
              else payment_number end )
from @TestData as t1
```